# i can not type in terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome-terminal

When I open the terminal, the window appears without the ability to write. I cannot type, and I also do not see the directory.
you can see the screenshot from this link:
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGrpM.png)
I have already tried killing all running processes and restarting the computer. Additionally, I attempted to reset the terminal..
How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you make any changes in the session(s) prior to this issue occurring, eg. change the default version of python3 etc. Your text terminals I'd still exist to work (eg. Ctrl+Alt+F4 to switch to a text terminal), allowing you to look at logs & remind yourself as to changes made, as I'd expect your issue to be related to changes made in the session (or two) before this occurred. As we don't know what you did, how often you perform upgrades etc.. we're limited.

Comment: @guiverc i was having an ssh issue so the last thing i remember is that i tested the connection git remote -v

Comment: If you don't even get a terminal prompt (and it's not simply because PS1 is unset) then either the terminal isn't starting a shell, or the shell isn't completing its initialization  - sometimes the latter is due to an infinite loop e.g. sourcing .profile from .bashrc and also sourcing .bashrc from .profile

Comment: @steeldriver what should i do in this situation please ??

Comment: Assuming your terminal is configured to use the bash shell, open the relevant (hidden) files (.profile, .bashrc, .bash_profile) from the file manager and check them. Or open the terminal's Preferences and change the command to `/bin/bash --noprofile --norc` or to an alternate shell such as `/bin/sh`.